# How to reduce white space between a stacked bar plot that is grouped

Tags: r

I am trying to create a grouped stack bar plot. I am nearly there (please see a small reproducible example below).

Test dataset below

```
structure(list(id = c("bmi", "bp.syst", "cholesterol", "current_smoker", 
"dm", "bmi", "bp.syst", "cholesterol", "current_smoker", "dm", 
"bmi", "bp.syst", "cholesterol", "current_smoker", "dm", "bmi", 
"bp.syst", "cholesterol", "current_smoker", "dm"), age_cat = c("50-59", 
"50-59", "50-59", "50-59", "50-59", "50-59", "50-59", "50-59", 
"50-59", "50-59", "50-59", "50-59", "50-59", "50-59", "50-59", 
"50-59", "50-59", "50-59", "50-59", "50-59"), sex = c("female", 
"female", "female", "female", "female", "female", "female", "female", 
"female", "female", "male", "male", "male", "male", "male", "male", 
"male", "male", "male", "male"), outcome = c("is", "is", "is", 
"is", "is", "mi", "mi", "mi", "mi", "mi", "is", "is", "is", "is", 
"is", "mi", "mi", "mi", "mi", "mi"), ce = c(-0.10256038920815, 
0.389531808498818, 0.189757379029111, 0.242653828895447, -0.00912095569278522, 
-0.0886249777508804, 0.30613965729692, 0.360665863387202, 0.243896737961612, 
-0.0510720373492212, -0.0872536577940028, 0.445136499987966, 
0.285697713680353, 0.173800331570914, -0.0165390351091511, -0.0753370972092315, 
0.353576764190506, 0.506875636047312, 0.174734750863782, -0.0874725134917425
)), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, 
-20L))
```

ggplot code below

```
ggplot() + 
  geom_bar(data=test, aes(x = ce, y=outcome, fill=id), position="stack", stat="identity",width=0.25)+
  geom_vline(xintercept = 0, color =c("white")) +
  scale_fill_viridis(option = "plasma",
                 discrete =T,
                 name = 'Risk factor',
                 labels = c('Body mass index', 'Systolic blood pressure', 'Cholesterol', 'Smoking',
'Diabetes'))+
  ggtitle("Potential impact fraction by condition and sex") +
  theme_ipsum() +
  theme(legend.position="right") +
  xlab('Percentage')+
  facet_grid(sex~1)
```

I want to significantly reduce the white space within the sex category but still keep some white space between the sex category

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can reduce the space between the bars with the `width` argument in `geom_bar` while the space between the facets can be set in `theme()` with `panel.spacing.y`. To get an additional parameter to control for the "width" of the bars I added `scale_y_discrete(expand = expansion(add = c(2, 2)))` which expands the y-axis thereby "squishing" the bars.

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(hrbrthemes)
library(viridis)
#> Loading required package: viridisLite
ggplot() + 
  geom_bar(data=test, aes(x = ce, y=outcome, fill=id), position="stack", stat="identity", width = .6)+
  geom_vline(xintercept = 0, color =c("white")) +
  scale_y_discrete(expand = expansion(add = c(2, 2))) +
  scale_fill_viridis(option = "plasma",
                     discrete =T,
                     name = 'Risk factor',
                     labels = c('Body mass index', 'Systolic blood pressure', 'Cholesterol', 'Smoking',
                                'Diabetes'))+
  ggtitle("Potential impact fraction by condition and sex") +
  theme_ipsum() +
  theme(legend.position="right", panel.spacing.y = unit(1, "cm")) +
  xlab('Percentage')+
  facet_grid(sex~1)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-06-08 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: this works and reduces the space between the males and females but i still want the height of each of the stacks to be 0.25 and the space to be say 0.05

Comment: Hi. I just edited my post to show an option to get back to your desired width of .25. Not perfect but ...

Answer (score 1):

You might use a combination of functions from `grid` and `gtable` packages to **visualize and alter** the spacing between different objects.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(viridis)    # for scale_fill_viridis
library(hrbrthemes) # for theme_ipsum
library(grid)       # for ggplot_build and ggplot_table
library(gtable)     # for gtable_show_layout

## create and save plot in object "plot_01"
plot_01 <- ggplot() + 
  geom_bar(data = test, aes(x = ce, y = outcome, fill = id), position = "stack", 
           stat = "identity", width = 0.25)+
  geom_vline(xintercept = 0, color = c("white")) +
  scale_fill_viridis(option = "plasma",
                     discrete = TRUE,
                     name = 'Risk factor',
                     labels = c('Body mass index', 'Systolic blood pressure', 
                                'Cholesterol', 'Smoking', Diabetes'))+
  ggtitle("Potential impact fraction by condition and sex") +
  theme_ipsum() +
  theme(legend.position = "right") +
  xlab('Percentage')+
  facet_grid(sex ~ 1)
```

This is your original plot, now saved to "plot_01"

```
plot_01
```

[image]

```
# make an object, that is easier accessible to change
grid_01 <- ggplot_gtable(ggplot_build(plot_01))

# look at the layout
# a visualisation makes this a lot easier
gtable_show_layout(grid_01)
```

This gives the original layout:

[image]

```
## make a copy to play around with
grid_02 <- grid_01
## increase the height between male/female times 4
grid_02$heights[9] <- grid_02$heights[9] * 4
```

If you compare the heights between grid_01 and grid_02, you see the difference:
[image]

```
## and look at the effect in the layout
gtable_show_layout(grid_02)
```

This produces the changed grid:

[image]

```
grid.newpage()      # needed to avoid plotting on top of existing plot
grid.draw(grid_02)  # plot your altered pic
```

This, in turn, gives you a graph with more spacing as you described.

[image]

Of course, you can toy around with this and other spaces in your plot.

Please let me know whether this is what you want.

Comment: thanks - how do i change reduce the space between the mi and is in the female category and same for the male category